# Comparing chars in C

Tags: c

I have a quick question. I have one method called test(). And my code looks like:

```
void test() 
{

    char c;
    printf("Are you happy?\n");
    printf("Hit y for yes or n for no \n");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    if(c == 'y') 
    {
        printf("That's awesome!\n");
    } 
    else 
    {
        printf("That is too bad.\n");
    }
}
```

When I run the code, the input is not read. I think my problem is in the line "if(c =='y')" Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong/how to fix it? Thanks!

p.s I have a main method etc.

Comment: All four answers are correct so I won't bother adding another one.  But when reading a single character it's simpler, safer and more efficient to use the getchar() function rather than scanf().

Answer (score 4):

This scans for an `int`:

```
scanf("%d", &c);
```

This scans for a `char`:

```
scanf("%c", &c);
```

Comment: +1 (you'll get a loooot of points for this one. **C** language questions are pretty popular) :-)

Comment: @Spencer: Suggest that you read up on and thoroughly understand the format specifiers before using scanf().  It's a very dangerous function when used incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

The proper `scanf` format specifier for reading a single `char` value is `"%c"`. You are using `"%d"`. Format specifier `"%d"` is intended to be used exclusively with `int` recipient arguments. Why are you trying to use `"%d"` with a `char`?

Comment: I will never make this mistake again. Just new with c trying to figure some things out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should change it to `scanf("%c", &c)`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `scanf`, it should have `%c` for reading a `char`

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/) for more details on `scanf`